# Use Unicode characters in strings.xml

Tags: android, string, unicode

I have the following unicode character that I want to use in a string:

I have found its hex and decimal code through [this](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%9A%95):

While I know how to use the "&" symbol in a string in `strings.xml` by doing this:

```
    <string name="Example">Example character &amp;</string>
```

I cannot use the car symbol.

How can I use this unicode character in a string in strings.xml?

Update One:

Following the first solution of using this: `&#128663;`
 I got the following error:`ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8:`

Comment: & symbol is denoted by this `&amp;`

Comment: @VivekMishra Sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: <string name="edit"></string>

Answer (score 54):

It's

```
<string name="Example">Example character \u0026</string>
```

See more unicode characters here:

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024&utf8=0x

Comment: This works really well, except you don't need the semicolumn (`\u0026`)

Comment: Oh I think this was a mistake due to normally end a line of code with semicolon ^^

Comment: This didn't work for me, so I just copied the character itself.

Comment: It seems that the approach doesn't work with characters whose unicode is coded with 5 symbols (e.g. `\u1f4cb`). However using the corresponding html entity `&#x1F4CB;` works.

Answer (score 16):

if you go Unicode site : https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character and click at this Unicode that says U+00AE you mustn't write the + symbol if you want copy paste this example at strings.xml
:) :) :)

```
<string name="example">"\u00AE"</string>
```

Comment: note doesn't work when unicode has 5 digits, need to use html &#x00AE; format

Answer (score 5):

```
<string name="ic_happy_font">&#xe902;</string>
```

or

```
<string name="edit"></string>
```

Answer (score 4):

Few important Unicode symbols for android strings.xml

```
<string name=”Rs”>\u20B9</string>
<string name=”filled_bullet”>\u25CF</string>
<string name=”linear_bullet”>\u25CB</string>
<string name=”rect_bullet”>\u25A0</string>
<string name=”blank_rect”>\u25A1</string>
<string name=”true_tick”>\u2713</string>
<string name=”star”>\u2605</string>
```

Full link is [here](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/special-character-in-android-c7f10a490911)

Comment: I was looking for star symbol

Answer (score 2):

Check that the XML is in UTF-8 and has `<?xml ... encoding="UTF-8"?>` or defaulted `<?xml ... ?>`.

First the Unicode code point is U+1F695 which is decimally 128661 (not ...3).

In XML content your approach is basically correct.

```
&#128661;
&#x1F695;
```

The error mentions "modified" UTF-8. This just means the code point U+0000, a binary 0, is also encoded as multi-byte sequence of bytes with high bit set. This is support for C where a "string" ends on a NUL byte.

As the TAXI code point needs 4 UTF-8 bytes, it might be that the XML on Android only supports less long UTF-8 sequences. At least for numeric entities `&#...;`.

If the entities are a problem, use an UTF-8 capable editor and paste the TAXI from the clipboard.

You might try whether there is a work-around, whether u-escaped chars are read *(probably not)*:

```
\uD83D\uDE95
```

A last wild attempt would be to use

```
<?xml version="1.1" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code point you have in your example is an [ellipsis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm). As per [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f697/index.htm), try

```
    &#128663;
```

Comment: This doesn't work I get this error: `ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8:`

Comment: i mean are you using java to parse an xml file, or xslt or some other language?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets underlined space although you didn't intent it, you can avoid this by using unicode code point of space

For example:

```
<string name="conditions">By signing in you agree to our <u>Terms &amp; 
Conditions.</u></string>
```

would also underline space before 'Terms & Conditions'

solution:

```
<string name="conditions">By signing in you agree to our\u0020<u>Terms &amp; 
Conditions.</u></string>
```